# Getter hits database, local variable does not?

Tags: c#, variables, scope

Best to explain with an example:

```
int RecordCount
{
   return dataAdapter.getCount(); // database access
}
```

Now, each time this is called in the code, there will be a database lookup. But what if I assign `RecordCount` to a local variable like so:

```
int recordCount = RecordCount;
// multiple calls to recordCount follow...
```

I assumed that each time local variable `recordCount` was accessed, there would be a database lookup because `recordCount` is just a reference to `RecordCount`. However, my colleague believes that a lookup will only happen upon the initial assignment, and then recordCount can be used freely with no more database penalty.

As the old Monday Night Football IBM ads use to say, You Make The Call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your colleague is right, you are wrong.

It has nothing to do with `recordCount` being a reference or not. Accesing a `field` does not have side effects.

If `recordCount` were a `property` then depending on the getter implementation you could have a database lookup, which is precisely what happens in `RecordCount`.

Comment: So in subsequent uses of `recordCount`, it doesn't matter if `recordCount` is an int or a homemade type. It's the fact that it's a field that has its own life, and once that initial assignment is made, it has nothing to do with `RecordCount` again, is that about right?

Comment: Yup. It doesn't matter if its a reference type or a value type. A similar example could be the following field (or local) assignment: `MyClass myClass = new MyClass();`. Whenever you access `myClass` you are not "newing" myClass with MyClass's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`RecordCount` returns an `int`, which is set as the value for `recordCount`. The getter only gets called when you reference `RecordCount` directly.

You aren't assigning `RecordCount` as a method to `recordCount`, but the value returned by `RecordCount`.

Answer (score 0):

int (System.Int32) is value type - so the value is copied on assignment (unlike reference types).

Note: Consider not to do costly operations in property getters.